# Mplayer does not work anymore and I don't know why or what happend

Tags: 11.10, command-line, bash, music, mplayer

[image: mplayer: relocation error: mplayer: symbol ff_codec_bmp_tags, version LIBAVFORMAT_53 not defined in file libavformat.so.53 with link time reference]

Whenever I try and sue mplayer it says:

```
mplayer: relocation error: mplayer: symbol ff_codec_bmp_tags, version LIBAVFORMAT_53 not defined in file libavformat.so.53 with link time reference
```

What do I do to fix this?

Comment: Looks to me like the file you're trying to play isn't in that directory. The closest thing is 'DrunkTank-DrunkTank42734.mp3.part'.

Comment: @Carborundum I tried doing it on a file that does not have a 'part' and the end and it stll said the same thing.

Comment: what is the terminal output if you try this command:        "sudo mplayer ~/Music/Rooster_Teeth_Podcast_151.mp3"

Comment: @v2r mplayer: relocation error: mplayer: symbol ff_codec_bmp_tags, version LIBAVFORMAT_53 not defined in file libavformat.so.53 with link time reference

Comment: @jaorizabal. thank you: it may be, that your ffms2 library is built against a different version of ffmpeg or libav, that is installed. try to update ffms2 in order to resolve this problem. "http://code.google.com/p/ffmpegsource/" i hope it works for you!

Comment: @v2r the link does not work. It says The page you asked for does not exist.

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience jaorizabal! please use the same link as posted above, since the menu (Project Home / Downloads / Wiki etc..) is linked correctly!

Comment: That looks like a broken `mplayer`. It doesn't match the libav/ffmpeg installed. Where did you get your `mplayer` from? Was it the one shipped with Ubuntu? Output of `dpkg -l 'libavformat*'` and `dpkg -l mplayer` please.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem on 11.10 and here's what solved my problem.

I updated my version installed from the Ubuntu Software Center with the latest build found on the [mplayer daily build site](https://launchpad.net/~motumedia/+archive/mplayer-daily) (I thought I'd take the risk since it wasn't working anyway).

I added the repository manually in a terminal like this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:motumedia/mplayer-daily
```

then update the versions available

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then I went to the Update Manager GUI (it's in the same menu as where you can shut down your system and is called "Software Up to Date") and selected all the available updates from this source (mplayer-daily).

After that, mplayer worked fine again for me.

This might not be the best way to install updates, I really don't know because I'm pretty much a newbie to Ubuntu, but at least it worked.

Hope this helps someone.